# Nginx Nested Location Priority

Tags: nginx, configuration

Here is part of my nginx configuration:

```
location ~ \.php$ {

    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;

}

location /wp-content/uploads/ {

    location ~ .(aspx|php|jsp|cgi)$ { return 410; }

}
```

As I understand it, the order of priority in location blocks goes like this:

```
  = (exact match)  -->  ^~ (preferential prefix)  -->  ~ (regex) or ~* (case-insensitive regex)  -->  (prefix - no special character)
```

I put a PHP file in `/wp-content/uploads`. I got a 410 response code (which is what I want). But I don't understand why the first location block didn't capture the request, since regex blocks take precedence over prefix.

Furthermore, when two regex locations match, the first declared regex location match takes the request. Yet the latter processes the request here.

Why am I getting the 410 response code for `/wp-content/uploads/info.php`?!?

Comment: You have `wp-config` and `wp-content` in your question - so as written the behaviour is entirely correct.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for noticing my mistake. I verified that the file is in the wp-content folder. It has been the whole time. I just wrote it wrong in the question, and have edited it.

Comment: Does the access log show the 410 response?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes it does. I found the answer. I'll post it here shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. There's a little-known secret of nginx location matching.

Here is the order of precedence, according to [artfulrobot.uk](https://artfulrobot.uk/blog/untangling-nginx-location-block-matching-algorithm):

```
1. Exact string matches location = /foo
2. The longest of any location ^~ ... matches
3. The first regex match that is nested within the single longest matching prefix match!
4. The first other regex match location ~ regex
5. The longest prefix match location /foo
```

Everybody knows about #1, #2, #4, and #5.

**But #3 is the gotcha. That's what is happening here.**

You'll want to read the article as he very granularly describes this seemingly undocumented and strange behavior of nginx.