# Nginx location not behaving as the docs suggest

Tags: php, docker, nginx, proxy, webserver

I have a query about the way nginx handles locations when try_files is invoked. I have a docker stack which serves Wordpress and phpmyadmin applications. My config is below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php;
    server_name test.com; # Just a placeholder
    root /code;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /pma {
        alias /var/www/html;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass phpmyadmin:9000;
        }
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

My question is this: Why does the above config work when according to the nginx documentation [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) it should not work.

When a request for 'http://test.com/pma/' is made I understand the following *should* happen:

1. Match /pma location
2. try_files $uri = FALSE
3. try_files $uri/ = FALSE
4. Fallback to /index.php
5. $uri now equal to: 'http://test.com/pma/index.php'
6. Processing is now restarted.
7. Match '.php$' location at the bottom.
8. It breaks because this is the wrong location and the 'php' container doesn't have access to the phpmyadmin files inside the 'phpmyadmin' container.

However, instead what appears to happen is this:

1. Match /pma location
2. try_files $uri = FALSE
3. try_files $uri/ = FALSE
4. Fallback to /index.php
5. $uri now equal to: 'http://test.com/pma/index.php'
6. Processing continues inside the '/pma' context, which now matches the nested '.php$' location block, which passes the request to FPM listening inside the 'phpmyadmin' container.

I know I should be happy that it works, but it's bugging me when everything I understand about nginx says this shouldn't work.

Obviously I have some fundamental misunderstanding about the way this works, and I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: As long as Nginx can resolve and access `phpmyadmin:9000` it should work as expected

Comment: It can, but the issue is the internal redirect caused by try_files when it gets to it's fallback option. At that point nginx does an internal redirect, and appends 'index.php' to the end of the URI. Processing should then be restarted which will cause the last (wrong) location block to match. 

Instead nginx is staying within the '/pma' location context and passing the request onto the 'phpmyadmin' container. This is great, because it works, but it's also from my understanding now how nginx processing should work.

Comment: I'm still not certain what you are expecting. Why do you _think_ it is going to the other `location` block? A request comes in prefixed with `/pma`, and phpMyAdmin is a single entry point app which routes all requests through index.php. So `/pma/config` will still load `index.php` which looks at the original request and figures out the code to run

Comment: Hi Chris,

I'm *expecting* it to fail. I know nginx is going into the nested location block because I can insert a header in there and then check the header in my browser afterwards.

As I said in the initial question, once the try_files gets hit in the /pma location block, it will fallback to index.php, this will then restart location processing, but now the $uri variable looks like this: /pma/index.php. This should match the last location block, which in turn will fail because the container called 'php' does not have the necessary content to service phpmyadmin.

Comment: But _why_ do you expect it to fail? That's what I'm not understanding. Is it because you think there's something special in the second `location ~ \.php$ {` block? The outer `/pma` block generally routes the requests for phpMyAdmin, including static assets like images, and the inner further qualifies it looking for just PHP files specifically. Also, there's no real "restart processing", the inner inherits from the parent, which further inherits from the server and so on.

Comment: I expect it to fail because the outer php location block wont route to the phpmyadmin container, it will just go to a generic php-fpm container for processing Wordpress.
Nginx by default will always restart processing after internal redirection. It doesn't matter where the rewrite happens, once it has happened location processing is restarted. Which means our rewritten URI now ends in .php, which will match the last location block, which won't work because it has no access to phpmyadmin. However, it is in fact working, which is what I don't understand. By its nature it should throw 500/404.

Comment: You can verify the behaviour yourself here: https://nginx.viraptor.info/

Create the same setup as myself above and then request the following URL: http://test.com/pma/index.php

See what I mean?

Comment: I'm sorry, I feel like we're talking in circles and I hope I'm not frustrating you. I'm going to ignore "containers" because Nginx isn't aware of them. The proxy/pass stuff is just a standard TCP connection. Once a location block matches, it will never break out unless an `@` rule exists. I'm not really clear what an "internal redirection" is for Nginx, not sure if you're trying to equate this to htaccess concepts somehow which do "restart". Is it that PMA doesn't live in `/var/www/html`?

Comment: Hey Chris, don't worry, you're not frustrating me. I've actually found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74140437/nginx-nested-location-priority

nginx has an undocumented way of processing nested location matches. I'll post the answer below for you to look at.

Comment: I’m happy you found an answer, but I’m still confused. You don’t have to respond, but I’d be curious if you could post a URL that you think shouldn’t work but does. Location blocks are determined in nest order, so outer happens first, always. Once the /pma match is determined to be the best, the inner just further qualifies additional potential matches. Or we just move on! Happy holidays!

Comment: Merry Christmas Chris! I'll split my answer into two replies...

Ok, so when the fallback option of the 'try_files' directive happens nginx will issue an internal rewrite. The docs specifically say that [HERE](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

Specifically: _If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made._

The importance of this is that when nginx detects a rewrite it immediatley stops processing the current context and restarts location matching. This is why the 'break' directive exists.

Comment: Now, because try_files has caused an internal redirect and our $uri now ends in .php, the last location block (A regex checking for a URI that ends in .php) would match. 

The nginx official documentation explicitly states this is the behavior that should occur [HERE](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) 
Specifically:

Comment: _To find location matching a given request, nginx first checks locations defined using the prefix strings (prefix locations). Among them, the location with the longest matching prefix is selected and remembered. Then regular expressions are checked, in the order of their appearance in the configuration file. The search of regular expressions terminates on the first match__

Comment: Because a regex match takes precedence over a prefix string match it should be the location block that nginx chooses, however that's not what happens because of the undocumented behavior which I have supplied as the answer below.

nginx instead matches the longest prefix, which also contains a regex match inside of it. In plain English this translates to: "Give me the URI starting with '/pma' and ends in '.php' 

No where in the official documentation is this stated. It's assumed knowledge and I'm bewildered no one though this important information shouldn't be included in the docs!

Comment: Chris I also think it's worth mentioning that while you're correct in the behavior you describe above is _how_ nginx processes location blocks, but my issue is that it's not the behavior one would expect when you read the docs. Literally no where does it say that nginx will do a prefix match, then enter that location, then try a regex match. I'm not alone in finding this omission strange: https://artfulrobot.uk/blog/untangling-nginx-location-block-matching-algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found here: https://artfulrobot.uk/blog/untangling-nginx-location-block-matching-algorithm

Specifically this part:

1. Exact string matches location = /foo
2. The longest of any location ^~ ... matches
3. The first regex match that is nested within the single longest matching prefix match! See discussion below.
4. The first other regex match location ~ regex
5. The longest prefix match location /foo

Point number '3' is the answer here.